# Is it good practice to insert blank lines into HTML code?

Tags: html

For example, to break up code into chunks for readability/maintainability, or is there a better method?
e.g:

```
<div class="list">
    <p class="list-item">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p class="list-author">Jane Doe</p>

    <p class="list-item">Another lorem ipsum</p>
    <p class="list-author">John doe</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try reading the [MDN HTML developers guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML). In my opinion I doubt it really matters but the answer' probably in the guide somewhere....

Comment: In such cases I prefer to insert a comment row stating the reason for the segregation, for ease of understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with using blank lines here to increase the readability/maintainability of your code. Another option is to use comments but be careful with HTML comments and do not put sensitive data/information in your comments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a block of code similar to my example comprising of about 200 lines, comments might work to make it easier to maintain individual sections.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to follow  Coding Conventions, you can follow this link...
[From W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp)

So don't put unnecessary blank space and as well as put necessary space to improve readability and maintainability.

Comment: [Don't use W3Schools](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280484/4575054).

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as it improve readability, I usually insert blank line for very big segments like 50+ rows. Often where php or javascript is inserted.

Machines doesnt care if there are blank rows but SEO optimalization might.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.